# Google Maps Autocomplete - street number disappears

Tags: google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API autocomplete. When I type in an address, I get suggestions. Valid results are bold, but invalid results are not. So, I might get an item in the drop down where the street name is bold, but the number is not:

[image]

So, if the users chooses 829 Wakely Terrace, I call getPlace and populate my address fields. But since its not a valid number, it looks like the number get stripped out.  This is a confusing experience.

Can I force autocomplete to not do this?

Concersely, do I need some kind of "Did you mean this address?" functionality? Can anyone point me to an example of where this is handled well (Not for code, but UX purposes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sort of answer. We were using the autocomplete widget from Google. Is till find it weird the whole bold/not bold thing, but if you use the AutocompleteService, you get the raw suggestions as JSON from Google. So, you need to do some more work to make the front end work, but you have a lot more control and con handle the situation as you see fit.